# Как в битриксе автоматически добавить ко всем файлам символьный код?

Tags: php, битрикс, cms, php5

Как в битриксе автоматически добавить ко всем файлам символьный код?

*Цель символьного кода: образовать url для товара, без символьного кода у меня пустой адрес на всех товарах, где нет символьного кода*

Создал в папке `php_interface` файл под названием `init.php`

Добавил такой код:

```
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd", "addElement");
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate",   array("MyEventHandlerClass", "IBlockElementAddCodeFromName"));

function addElement($arFields){

      $arParams = array(
               "max_len" => "60", // обрезаем символьный код до 60 символов
               "change_case" => "L", // приводим к нижнему регистру
               "replace_space" => "-", // меняем пробелы на тире
               "replace_other" => "-", // мен¤ем плохие символы на тире
               "delete_repeat_replace" => "true", // удаляем повтор¤ющиеся тире
               "use_google" => "false", // отключаем использование google
            );

      $arFields["CODE"] = Cutil::translit($arFields["NAME"], "ru", $arParams);

}
```

Сохранил, обновил кеш, но данные не изменились, т.е. ни одному товару не добавился символьный код. Может дополнительно как-то нужно вызвать функцию или еще что-то делать? Может есть другие варианты?

Comment: А что вы сохранили? Файл?

Comment: Да, сохранил файл init.php, на котором код, который указал выше

Comment: Ну и чего вы ожидаете теперь? Почему вы думаете что ваш обработчик выполнился?

Comment: А как вызвать? Вижу что нужно функцию вызвать, но не понятно где и как вызвать

Answer (score 0):

Наверно вам надо к файлам или к товарам добавлять символьный код? К товарам добавляется:

В Каталоге товаров в Настройках информационного блока вкладка Поля поставить галочку Символьный код и выставить настройки

[image: Символьный код инфоблока Битрикс]